# No visible @interface for 'Appdelegate' declares the selector 'setupTabBarController'

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, appdelegate

I have created a method in `Appdelegate.m`

```
-(void)setupTabBarController {
         // details goes here
}
```

Now in `ABC.m` I want to access the `setupTabBarController`

I have included app delegate:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

And then:

```
AppDelegate *maindelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
[maindelegate setupTabBarController];
```

But it's showing the error,

> No visible @interface for 'Appdelegate' declares the selector 'setupTabBarController'

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the error message states, you need to declare it in `AppDelegate.h` and then you should call it as:

```
AppDelegate *maindelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[maindelegate setupTabBarController];
```

In AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

- (void)setupTabBarController;

@end
```

Comment: Check again. I am sure you didnt declare in `AppDelegate.h` class.

Comment: @Shyantanu, Nice to know that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare this methosd in Appdelegate.h file to use it in another view controller like this

```
-(void)setupTabBarController;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate setupTabBarController];
```